# Concatenating strings based on previous row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

Consider the following input:

```
ID
--------
33
272
317
318
```

I need to somehow get the following result:

```
Result
--------
/33
/33/272
/33/272/317
/33/272/317/318
```

How can I achieve this with a single SELECT statement?

Comment: What determines the order?

Comment: The row sequence determines the order. So I can use ROW_NUMBER OVER (SELECT NULL) to order those rows...

Comment: Tables have **no** inherent order. `ROW_NUMBER OVER (SELECT NULL)` is a convoluted way to tell the system "I don't *care* what order you do things in"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, I know. I just wanted to learn the main technique and I'm definitely not going to use SELECT NULL to order those rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH()`:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte c
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID)
    FROM Cte
    WHERE rn <= c.rn
    FOR XML PATH('')
)x(s)
```

Comment: Awesome. I tried everything to do this for the past hour and I failed over and over again. Thank you.